# XPATH expression to match context-param in web.xml

Tags: xml, xpath

What will be xpath expression to match the context-param with param-name foo as shown below:

```
<web-app>

  <context-param>
     <param-name>foo</param-name>
     <param-value>bar</param-value>
     <description></description>
   </context-param>
.....
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/web-app/context-param[param-name/text() = 'foo']`

Answer (score 1):

```
//context-param[param-name='foo']
```

should do it. `//context-param` asks for a list of all the nodes that is are descendants of the context node (i.e. the document root) with the name "context-param". The bit in square brackets then filters this list for context-param nodes which have a direct descendant with the name "param-name" and a text "foo". `='foo'` is shorthand for `/text()='foo'`.

Also, watch out for namespaces in real use!

Comment: You need to remove the "/" from `[/param-name='foo']` in order for this to return anything. (should be `/web-app/context-param[param-name = 'foo']` )

Comment: Taking namespace issue into account I ended up with `//*[local-name()='context-param'][*[local-name()='param-name']='foo']`